# Print string letter by letter in UI Text

Tags: unity, c#, text, ui-design

i'm trying to print a string letter by letter for UI Text of Unity.
With each click of a button, the Stampa function, must print a letter. Up to this point everything is working perfectly.
But if I try to print a newline "\n" the function ignores him and continues to print on the same line.
This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Click : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Text txt;
    public static int indice = 0;
    public string asd = "String1 \nStriga2";

    void Awake() {
        txt = GameObject.Find("Cmd").GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    }

    public void Clicked() {
        Stampa(asd ,indice);
        indice++;
    }

    void Stampa(string stringa, int i) {
        txt.text += stringa[i];
    }

}
```

That produces this result(unwanted): [image]

I also tried to print the entire string at the same time (not a letter at a time) as follows:

```
txt.text = "String1 \nStriga2";
```

That produces this result(wanted): [image]
How can I get this second result by printing letter by letter?

Comment: Check if `string[i]` is a slash, if it is then add both `i` and `i+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's reading one character at a time, so it's not properly escaping the new line.  I would suggest looking for escape characters in your Stampa() function, and if it's an escape character, read the next character in at the same time.  Something like:

```
void Stampa(string stringa, int i) {
    string r = stringa[i];
    if (r == '\\')
       r += stringa[i+1];
    txt.text += r;
}
```

Thought you'd likely need to return the index value to the calling function.  You could return an int and maybe do something like this:

```
public void Clicked() {
        int val = Stampa(asd, indice);
        indice += val;
    }

int Stampa(string stringa, int i) {
        int ret = 1;
        string s = stringa[i];
        if (s == '\\')
        {
           s += stringa[i+1];
           ret++;
        }
        txt.text += s;

        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: Nice solution, I have not assessed the fact that he read '\n' separately.

Comment: It's an easy miss since dealing with larger strings it's basically read in as a single character.  I'm glad it helped!

Comment: @Amarildo, I accepted your change from `string` to `char`, then reverted the change back because the value of `s` can be more than one character - that was the whole point of the added code, to allow `string s = "\\nS"` or something similar, right?  Two character, the newline and the next character in from your `asd` value.